# Resteasy client not working from office, but working from home

Tags: rest, timeout, resteasy, restful-authentication

I am using RestEasy client api, to make call to some internal api, but when I run the code from my home I am able to get the response without any timeout exception. But when I run from office getting timeout execution, am I missing any configurations?

> I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Operation timed out

Below the code am using:

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(
                    "https://example.com/v2");
            request.queryParameter("name", "jhon");
            request.accept("application/json");


            ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);


            if(response.getStatus() == 404){
                System.out.println(response.getEntity());

                System.out.println(response.getStatus());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
                JSONObject d = new JSONObject(output);
                JSONObject sd = d.getJSONObject("Error");

                System.out.println(sd.get("Detail"));
            }
```

Comment: am thinking , we might need add proxy details , but not sure how to add proxy details , if i add proxy details , does it work from home ? , not sure ,

Comment: Where is the server example.com located at? Can you `ping example.com` from the office?